# Can't compile 64 bits Visual Studio 2010 projects

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc, 64-bit, linker-errors

I have several VS 2010 projects that I can not compile at 64 bits (32 bits builds worke fine without any problem). I did extensive things, like Reset Visual Studio Settings, first by IDE, after by command line; repair, reinstall, etc. and could not compile the projects. It was always telling me that

`cannot find ******.lib`

where the lib file was always a system library. Examples:

```
fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'shlwapi.lib'
fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'kernel32.lib'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After I asked a colleague for help, we noticed, that even getting clean builds of the projects from TFS, with overwrite option, the Project's Configuration Properties > VC++ Directories on my computer were always different from other computers.

Searching more we found the solution on the last post of [Reset include/lib path](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d87711ec-a44e-4897-8d63-da979e934f8a/reset-includelib-path?forum=vcgeneral), which I will fully transcribe:

> use "del %HOMEPATH%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\MSBuild\v4.0\Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user.props" is not always the right way.
>
> Better use "del %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\MSBuild\v4.0\Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user.props" where the application data folder is normally placed in.

Then I've looked inside the contents of `Microsoft.Cpp.x64.user.props` and I've seen that there were things added by Visual Leaks Detector. Which is reasonable, as one month before, I did a memory leak analysis using VLD.

So, I deleted the file and now everything compiles fine at 64bits!