# Python pip install with LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'kernel32.lib' with VC 2017

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio, pip, visual-studio-2017

Just installed Windows 7 Ultimate and Python on this computer within the last week.  So everything is fresh.  When I try to `pip install` something as simple as

```
pip install twisted
```

It goes through the process, then stalls out and complaints about:

```
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools
\MSVC\14.13.26128\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL
 /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:c:\python36\libs 
/LIBPATHc:\python36\PCbuild\amd64 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.13.26128\lib\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files((x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.13.26128\lib\x86" /EXPORT:PyIinit_raiser build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release
\src/twisted/test/raiser.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\twisted
\test\raiser.cp36-win_amd6.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win0amd64-3.6\Release
\src/twisted/test\raiser.cp36-win_amd64.lib'

LINK: fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'kernel32.lib'
```

I've done a search. There are 17 `kernel32.lib` files in various folders on my drive that have been installed by all the programming suites etc I've installed.

I have been researching this and cannot find a solution that works.

Reinstalling VC++ 2017 doesn't work.  Installing "Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7" doesn't work.  I've tried adding `"PATH"'s` to direct the files to the `kernel32.lib` and that hasn't worked either.

When I open Visual Studio, go to `Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > VC++ Directories` it states:

```
VC++ Directories editing in Tools > Options has been deprecated.

VC++ Directories are now available as a user property sheet that is added by
default to all projects.
```

But I'm just doing a `pip install` in Python, I'm not making a C++ program.

Is it possible Microsoft has basically disabled my ability to use these files from via a `pip install`?

How do I fix this so I can install my packages properly?

Edit:  This question is different from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39514632/error-cannot-open-file-kernel32-lib) as that question was for different versions of VS and the answers to that question did not work and or did not apply.

Comment: *But I'm just doing a pip install in Python, I'm not making a C++ program.* You're installing from sources (Twisted doesn't provide binary wheels) a python package that has C/C++ extensions so `pip` has to compile them.

Comment: What I mean is VC++ is telling me to use a "user property sheet" to change the folders, but since I'm not building a c++ program in VC++, that solution doesn't appear to apply.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the exact same error when pip install nes_py on windows, I was able to resolve it by adding `Windows 10 SDK (10.0.18362.0)` through Visual Studio Installer

Answer (score 0):

It was helpful for me:

`python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel`