# How to fix meson generating an incorrect linker flag (--subsystem console)

Tags: clang, ninja, meson-build

I've created a simple project to get myself accustomed to meson, but the build keeps failing.

This is what I did (to set up the environment, and to build):

```
set CC=clang
set CC_LD=lld
set CFLAGS="--target x86_64-pc-windows-msvc"
meson build
cd build
ninja
```

My `meson.build` is as follows:

```
project('EtaClient', 'c')
src = ['src/main.c', 'src/linkedlist.c']
executable('EtaClient', src)
target = 'x86_64-pc-windows-msvc'
```

While building, I get the following errors (the obj files are built successfully, but they're not linked and thus the exe isn't built):

```
LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/-subsystem'; ignored
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'console.obj'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1181 (use -v to see invocation)
```

When I look in my `build.ninja` to see what's going on, I find:

```
build EtaClient.exe | EtaClient.pdb: c_LINKER EtaClient.exe.p/src_main.c.obj EtaClient.exe.p/src_linkedlist.c.obj
LINK_ARGS = "-Wl,/nologo" "-Wl,/release" "-Wl,/nologo" "-Wl,/DEBUG" "-Wl,/PDB:EtaClient.pdb" "-Wl,--subsystem,console" "-lkernel32" "-luser32" "-lgdi32" "-lwinspool" "-lshell32" "-lole32" "-loleaut32" "-luuid" "-lcomdlg32" "-ladvapi32"
```

I replace `"-Wl,--subsystem,console"` with `"-Wl,/subsystem:console"`, and the build compiles successfully, but I have to manually make this edit each time I modify my `meson.build`.

Could someone tell me why this happens, and how to set up meson to generate the correct flag?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use clang-cl instead of clang and leave out the defintion of the linker when you are on windows

```
set CC=clang-cl
set CFLAGS="--target x86_64-pc-windows-msvc"
meson build
cd build
ninja
```

see
https://github.com/mesonbuild/meson/issues/4232

Comment: I'll try it out, and if it works, I'll mark this answer as accepted :)

Comment: Just tested it, now the flag is output correctly but the linker (it automatically selected `lld-link`) is unable to find the windows `.lib` files (`kernel32.lib`, `user32.lib`, `shell32.lib`, etc.), any ideas?

Comment: @TheMadHau5,
this is a limitation of clang under windows
see https://stackoverflow.com/a/58905323/14683662

Comment: Thing is, I already do have MSVC installed (with Visual Studio 2019). I also have MSYS2 installed so I'll take a look using that then.

Comment: Note: clang works fine with the MSVC libs when running with the environment I gave in the question, but the build.ninja file generated by meson has one incorrect flag. Using the clang-cl environment suggested by you however, this is not the case, and the libraries can not be found. It's around 3 am here, so I'll be checking the MSYS solution in the morning. Thanks for helping me as much as you did :)

Comment: Update: I tried the MinGW toolchain and it works! (`lld` doesn't but I'll stick with the default one in that case). Now it's actually 3 am, so I'm going to go to sleep. Again, thank you for your help.