# How to build dpdk examples on windows

Tags: windows, ninja, dpdk, meson-build

I am able to follow the directions on the dpdk docs for windows.
http://doc.dpdk.org/guides/windows_gsg/build_dpdk.html

I am able to run `meson build` and `ninja -C build` and everything seems to work. The problem is whenever I run with the flag -Dexamples=helloworld, or any example for that matter, I get the following failure after running `ninja -C build`

```
FAILED: examples/dpdk-helloworld.exe
"clang"  -Wl,/MACHINE:X64 -Wl,/OUT:examples/dpdk-helloworld.exe examples/dpdk-helloworld.exe.p/helloworld_main.c.obj "-Wl,/nologo" "-Wl,/release" "-Wl,/nologo" "-Wl,/OPT:REF" "-Wl,/WHOLEARCHIVE:lib\librte_hash.a" "-Wl,/WHOLEARCHIVE:lib\librte_cmdline.a" "-Wl,/WHOLEARCHIVE:lib\librte_pci.a" "-Wl,/WHOLEARCHIVE:lib\librte_ethdev.a" "-Wl,/WHOLEARCHIVE:lib\librte_meter.a" "-Wl,/WHOLEARCHIVE:lib\librte_net.a" "-Wl,/WHOLEARCHIVE:lib\librte_mbuf.a" "-Wl,/WHOLEARCHIVE:lib\librte_mempool.a" "-Wl,/WHOLEARCHIVE:lib\librte_rcu.a" "-Wl,/WHOLEARCHIVE:lib\librte_ring.a" "-Wl,/WHOLEARCHIVE:lib\librte_eal.a" "-Wl,/WHOLEARCHIVE:lib\librte_telemetry.a" "-Wl,/WHOLEARCHIVE:lib\librte_kvargs.a" "-Wl,/WHOLEARCHIVE:drivers\librte_bus_pci.a" "-Wl,/WHOLEARCHIVE:drivers\librte_bus_vdev.a" "-Wl,/WHOLEARCHIVE:drivers\librte_mempool_ring.a" "-lws2_32" "-lmincore" "-ladvapi32" "-lsetupapi" "-ldbghelp" "lib\librte_hash.a" "lib\librte_cmdline.a" "lib\librte_pci.a" "lib\librte_ethdev.a" "lib\librte_meter.a" "lib\librte_net.a" "lib\librte_mbuf.a" "lib\librte_mempool.a" "lib\librte_rcu.a" "lib\librte_ring.a" "lib\librte_eal.a" "lib\librte_telemetry.a" "lib\librte_kvargs.a" "drivers\librte_bus_pci.a" "drivers\librte_bus_vdev.a" "drivers\librte_mempool_ring.a" "-Wl,--subsystem,console" "-lkernel32" "-luser32" "-lgdi32" "-lwinspool" "-lshell32" "-lole32" "-loleaut32" "-luuid" "-lcomdlg32"
LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/-subsystem'; ignored
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'console.obj'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1181 (use -v to see invocation)
[179/181] Linking target lib/rte_hash-21.dll
   Creating library lib\rte_hash.lib and object lib\rte_hash.exp
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Comment: looks like clang console related nitpick. Can you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64911334/how-to-fix-meson-generating-an-incorrect-linker-flag-subsystem-console. Let me know if it helps

Comment: I am able to build and use for both DPDK 20.11 and 21.02. Were you able get past the issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix meson generating an incorrect linker flag (--subsystem console)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64911334/how-to-fix-meson-generating-an-incorrect-linker-flag-subsystem-console)