# Meson "Error: Compiler cl cannot compile programs." (windows 10)

Tags: meson-build

(Hi, I am a beginner and have no experience with tool chain or any framework whatsoever. I only have a rough idea of what the commands mean.)
I was following a [guide](https://mesonbuild.com/SimpleStart.html) and when I ran the command:
`meson init --name testproject --build`

It gave the following output along with an error:

```
Using "testproject" (project name) as name of executable to build.
Defaulting to generating a C language project.
Sample project created. To build it run the
following commands:

meson setup builddir
meson compile -C builddir

Building...
The Meson build system
Version: 1.2.1
Source dir: E:\Dawg\testproject
Build dir: E:\Dawg\testproject\build
Build type: native build
Project name: testproject
Project version: 0.1

meson.build:1:0: ERROR: Compiler cl cannot compile programs
```

I tried googling the error and I got even more confused by different source using terms that are unknown to me.
I already had Visual Studio Build tools 2022 installed, so I didn't follow the toolchain installation step in the [guide](https://mesonbuild.com/SimpleStart.html), is that the reason why the error is occurring?
And if that's the case than what other good alternate methods are there to build a framework/project from source without me having to download a 7.61 gb build tool ([(2nd screenshot)](https://mesonbuild.com/SimpleStart.html)?

Comment: Did you install the Visual Studio toolchain ?

Answer (score 1):

If you check the logs you'll see the real error is "error cannot open file 'kernel32.lib'" So I found another thread ([error cannot open file 'kernel32.lib'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39514632/error-cannot-open-file-kernel32-lib)) that solved that problem.

This solution is what worked for me:
"I had to install the Visual C++ for Desktop Development.

Open Visual Studio Installer and go to Installed tab. Click on the Change Button on your installed Visual Studio Community Edition. -> On the Workloads Tab there should be a option Desktop Development with C++. Activate that option and modify the changes.

Afterwards it was working for me." from Marcel R.

I already had it activated but I noticed on the side bar, it had autoselected windows 11 SDK so I changed that to the latest windows 10 SDK and reinstalled everything then it worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the Developer Command Prompt or Native Tools Command Prompt. This is just the normal prompt but with environment variables configured to give you access to your compiler toolchain.

In your case 'cl' is looking for a C++ backend (I think) and not being able to find one. This shouldn't be an issue in the Developer Prompt.