# Issue with starting C++ development with visual studio code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, visual-c++, cl

I am trying to start developing with C++ in microsoft's visual studio code.

I have visual studio build tools installed with the "desktop development with C++"

I have the C++ extension in vs code installed.

I get an error whenever I try to run a .cpp file

Pls help

I take the following steps:

- I run the developer command prompt for visual studio
- I navigate to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\projects\helloworld"
- I type "code ."
- visual studio code opens and I create a "main.cpp" file
- I enter the code:

```
    int main(){
        return 0;
    }
```

- I click "run C/C++ file" and select "C/C++: cl.exe build and debug active file"
- It attempts to run but pops up the error message "The preLaunchTask 'C/C++: cl.exe build and debug active file' terminated with exit code -1
- The full error message is as follows:

```
Starting build...
cl.exe /Zi /EHsc /nologo "/FeC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\projects\helloworld\main.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\projects\helloworld\main.cpp"
main.cpp
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'kernel32.lib'

Build finished with error(s).

 *  The terminal process terminated with exit code: -1. 
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

Comment: When you run `code .` from a developer command prompt, make sure there are no other VSC windows open, just in case. If this doesn't help, I would reinstall VS (not VSC).

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22fatal+error+LNK1104%3A+cannot+open+file+%27kernel32.lib%27%22 there are a lot of Q&A about a similar message already. you should check if any of those help you.

Comment: your environment you're running cl.exe in lacks locations for library(ies) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39514632/error-cannot-open-file-kernel32-lib

Comment: You are using VSCode as a wrapper for Visual Studio? That's an odd combination, just use Visual Studio, that will make your life a lot simpler. (Just in case you are not aware, Visual Studio Code and Visual Studio are two separate products, either can be used without the other).

Comment: Did you start from the x64 native vs command prompt? You might also want to try https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc#_run-vs-code-outside-the-developer-command-prompt

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to compile it with Visual Studio Code. They have a great tutorial you can follow [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp). However, the part you would want to start is [how to install MinGW-x64](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp#_example-install-mingwx64-on-windows). Once that is done, the best way I have found to compile the programs is through the terminal window you can open in VSCode. Then run this `g++ insert_code_name.cpp -o insert_code_name`. Then, to run that code do `./insert_code_name`. If you need any further help, just let me know!